# Balanced Split Element after removing one element

Tags: arrays

I got a DSA question in a Google interview. I was able to do it in N-Square time complexity.

I take each item and try to check if the remaining elements can be divided into two equal arrays or not.

**Does anyone know any better time complexity solution?**

You are given an array of integers. Your task is to find an element in the array that, when removed, allows the remaining elements to be split into two parts with equal sums. The element to be removed can be located anywhere in the array, such as the first index, the last index, or any index in between.

Write a function or algorithm to identify and return the element that should be removed to achieve this balanced split. If no such element exists, the algorithm should return an appropriate indication (e.g., None or a specific message).

Example:

arr = [1,5,2,3]
remove the first element, then the remaining array can be divided into two equal sum arrays.

arr = [3,1,6,2,5]
remove the element of index 1, then [3,5] [6,2] will make two equal sum arrays.

Comment: `dsa` tag removed. Not relevant here (read tag description)